# Deletingdata from subquery return 0 erased

Tags: mysql

I cannot figure out the mistake in this query! Why is this row returning 0 but my data still remains? can someone please help?

```
DELETE FROM tasks 
WHERE  task_id = 50 
AND createdby IN((SELECT u1.user_id 
                  FROM   users u1 
                  WHERE  u1.user_team IN(SELECT u2.user_team 
                                         FROM   users u2 
                                         WHERE  u2.user_role <= (SELECT u3.user_id 
                                                                 FROM users u3 
                                                                 WHERE u3.user_id = 1))))
```

Comment: Oh my God how can we guess without data?

Comment: Row returning 0? Are you sure the output isn't that 0 rows affected (i.e. your query isn't returning any results)? Try running the statement as a select before trying to delete from it

Comment: the select is also returning 0 result, this i tried already. @Giorgi Nakeuri: what Data do you need: When run the first part  before the AND it returns the required row. Since the rest is self reference...?

Comment: @jhondano, try this select `select * FROM tasks 
WHERE  task_id = 50 
AND createdby IN((SELECT u1.user_id 
                  FROM   users u1 
                  WHERE  u1.user_team IN(SELECT u2.user_team 
                                         FROM   users u2 
                                         WHERE  u2.user_role <= (SELECT u3.user_id 
                                                                 FROM users u3 
                                                                 WHERE u3.user_id = 1)))) `. If it doesn't returns any row what do you expect to delete?

Comment: it returns my team codes! I am trying to delete the row in my tasks table which have the same id as task_id if rest of the matching fits.

Comment: @jhondano, if it returned rows then delete should work just fine. See if you have some instead of delete triggers on tasks table.